# C# Text Reader and Writer

Tags: c#, programming-languages

I have a text file here, the text is arranged in columns. What i need to do is read the text file in, format it so that each column starts on a new line. After the file has been read and formatted it needs to be written to a new file.... How would i go about doing this.

The file that need to be inputed looks like this:

Operator ID           = BTA020

Name                  = ASIA CHAMBEGA
Active profile        = User_Disabled
Enable status         = Disabled
Re-enable date        = 31/12/36 00:00:00
Approval status       = Approved
Last changed          = 21/07/10 07:34:30
Last sign-on          = 13/06/08 14:09:37
Calculated pwd        = BD
One-time password     = No
Assigned unit         = None

Operator ID           = BTAC002

Name                  = A KALATA (NBC)
Active profile        = User_Disabled
Enable status         = Disabled
Re-enable date        = 31/12/36 00:00:00
Approval status       = Approved
Last changed          = 31/05/10 14:04:41
Last sign-on          = n/a
Calculated pwd        = B9
One-time password     = No
Assigned unit         = None

The output fie should look like this:

Operator ID BTA020, Name ASIA CHAMBEGA, Active profile User_Disabled, Enable Status Disabled, Re-enable date 31/12/
Operator ID BTAC002, Name A Kalata (NBC), Active profile User_Disabled, Enable Status Disabled

// and so forth for 149 records

How would i get the output to look like this?

Thanks
Tren

Comment: How are the columns represented? Are they tab separated? If there originally `m` columns and `n` lines, do you want `m * n` lines in the output?

Comment: Okay i have edited the question and now you can see clearly what i am working with, and what the output needs to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a simple converter. Just read complete file (its not big in you case, so it can be read into memmory). And when replase '=' with ' ' and '\n' with ','. Transfromation is complete! After that, resulting text should be writen into new file. thats all!

code should be like this:

```
        string t = File.ReadAllText(path);

        t = t.Replace('=', ' ');
        t = t.Replace("\r\n\r\n", ",");
        t = t.Replace("\r\n", ",");
        t = t.Replace("\n", ",");
        t = t.Replace("  ", " ");
```

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for your assistance, the code works well enough but the formatting is still not 100%. It looks as follows: BTA020                , ASIA CHAMBEGA   

Active profile        , User_Disabled

Comment: OK, i fexed code. This revision should work properly. Its not elegant but it simple and works)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
using (TextReader textReader = ...)
using (TextWriter textWriter = ...)
{
    string line;

    while ((line = textReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // split into columns here
        string[] columns = ...;

        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            textWriter.WriteLine(column);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you could likely tighten this code up a bit using LINQ.

Comment: You are provide solution for case "each line contains several colums" but it was asked about "each column starts on a new line"

Comment: I would not agree with that, Anton. It's more like one line contains several columns in the input file and the output should be one line per column.

Comment: @Matten. According to example provided its something about ini file, but more complex. and each line actualy contains only one column

Comment: My answer was provided before the edit using what little information I had.

Answer (score 0):

For basic information regarding how to write and read follow the article

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/CSAndTypes11092005011259AM/CSAndTypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText( path );
string[] lines = data.Split('\t'); //I assume that "columns" mean tab seperated
File.WriteAllLines( path2, lines );
```

Or you can go for the one liner variant, but I prefer the first one for readability:

```
File.WriteAllLines( destinationPath, File.ReadAllText( sourcePath ).Split('\t') );
```